# During the game of war, if you could order the cards in your deck of 26, what strategy should you employ?

Tags: game-theory

During the game of war, if you could order the cards in your deck of 26, what strategy should you employ?

1. Assume Player 2 has a random ordering of 26 cards and is not allowed to change the order in anyway.
2. Let Player 1 have the advantage of looking at one's own deck of cards and reordering the cards.

Several theories may apply: game theory, combinatorics, simulation, etc.  What are some of the ideas that would help one dissect this problem into something useful and begin to solve it? By solve, I mean describe the strategy Player 1 should employ and why he should employ it.

Comment: A plausibly interesting-enough question, but would be more appropriate for MathStackExchange.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11503/does-war-have-infinite-expected-length may be relevant, as in the answers therein include an ordering of an infinitely long game.

Comment: I had seen that question, @MarkS. It discusses the outcome under the basic rules, not a variant in which a player orders his deck.

Comment: Upon reflection, if this question is construed as addressing the larger game-theoretic issue, then (so far as I know) it is worth keeping on this site. (I did not vote to close, in any case.)

Comment: @MarkJonesJr. any chance you can formalize the question better?

Comment: It seems to me that a natural formulation is to consider this as a zero sum game and look for a Nash equilibrium in mixed strategies -- if both players choose a probability distribution over orderings what are the equilibrium strategies.  Another interesting question is whether the uniform distribution is exploitable -- ie is there a strategy better than the uniform distribution against the uniform distribution? Lastly, how do these issues depend on the actual deals -- ie who got which cards.